# Setting Value programmatically in KendoUI multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui

I have my KendoUI MultiSelect widget initialized like this:

```
 $("#" + key).kendoMultiSelect({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        dataTextField: dataText,
        dataValueField: dataValue,
        filter: "contains",
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
            type: "jsonp",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: urlValue
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        value: GetSavedJSONObject(key),
        //value:  [
                //{ Name: "Chang", Id: 2 },
               // { Name: "Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears", Id: 7 }
            //],
        select: removeMark,
        change: multiselect_checkForChanges,
        autoClose: isAutoClose
    });
```

where GetSavedJSONObject(key) is an array of objects like this:

```
[Object { Id=1, Name="AA"}, Object { Id=2, Name="BB"}]
```

The issue I'm facing is when the page loads, I can see "AA" and "BB" in the multiselect widget and no call is made to the url. However, when I attempt to add more items to the widget, there are none to be added because the widget thinks the only items available are the items I specified in the "value" field of the widget during initialization.

In the [Server Filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/serverfiltering) demo, you will see that the example sets the value of the widget just like I did but when you try to add more items to the widget, then a call is made to the url for more data and the widget opens.

I'm sure this is user error but I just need some pointers on what to try next in order to get the widget to display the rest of the data.

EDIT:
When I made GetSavedJSONObject(key) return an array of the Ids so

```
[1,2,3]
```

I was able to click on the widget to get the rest of the data. However, the desired outcome is being able to set the values of the widget (because I have the Id/Name pairs) *without* having to make the call to the datasource *and* being able to click on the widget to fetch the rest of the data)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping my array of Objects and setting the serverFiltering: true attribute fixed the issue. Hope this saves someone else time. *sigh*